# Show Print Format in Jupyter Widgets

Tags: python-2.7, widget, jupyter

I have a result from the `classification_report` from `sklearn.metrics` and then `print` the report it would be like:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          1       1.00      0.84      0.91        43
          2       0.12      1.00      0.22         1

avg / total       0.98      0.84      0.90        44
```

Now, the question is how can I show the result in a Jupyter widget (in the above format) and update its value? 
Currently, I am using `html` widgets to show the result:

```
#pass test and result vectors
report = classification_report(pred_test , self.y_test_data) 
predict_table = widgets.HTML(value = "")
predict_table.value = report
```

but it likes the following:

```
precision recall f1-score support 1 1.00 0.81 0.90 43 2 0.00 0.00 0.00 0 avg / total 1.00 0.81 0.90 43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution using html techniques! As we are using html widget in Jupyter, the problem can be solved by using `pre` tag in html:

```
predict_table.value = "<pre>" + report + "</pre>
```